# User defined Field Removed after update sent items VSTO outlook c#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I have a user property which add a Flag of yes/no to the mail item column. I am adding that property when user sends an email and it comes to sent item. I am able to add the property and displaying correctly but after sent items folder updates its just vanishes. I am not able to find any reason. Below is the code.

```
MailItemInfo objInfo = new MailItemInfo(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI"));
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem msg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)item;                    
                objInfo.SetStoreIDAndEntryID(msg);
                MailUtilities util = new MailUtilities();

                 var userproperty = msg.UserProperties.Add("SaveSend", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olYesNo, true, 1);
                userproperty.Value = true;
                msg.Save(); // for saving mail item
```

Looking for some help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to define the user property on the Sent Items folder. Try to check the [Folder.UserDefinedProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/folder-userdefinedproperties-property-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm2021)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) property which returns a [UserDefinedProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/userdefinedproperties-object-outlook) object that represents the user-defined custom properties for the Folder object.

The `UserDefinedProperties` collection contains only the definitions of user-defined properties, which are applicable to all Outlook items contained by the folder. To retrieve or change user-defined property values for an Outlook item in that folder, use the `UserProperties` property of the Outlook item, such as a `MailItem` object, to retrieve the `UserProperties` collection for that item. You can then use the `UserProperty` object for the appropriate user-defined property to retrieve or change the value of that user-defined property for the Outlook item.

Comment: Eugene, doc of [UserProperties.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add) says that the 3rd optional parameter is **AddToFolderFields**, that by default, it is True., like OP enforce on his code. His code should have set it at Sent Folder level, not at Item level, don't?
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties), it is even clearer:
_it can also be added as a custom field to the folder that contains the item (using the same name as the property)_

Comment: As a side note, if my understanding is correct, MS should have named it **AlsoAddItToFolderFields**...